# How to use nerdtree and mvim behave like netbeans or eclipse?

Tags: macos, directory, vi

I want to use mvim as my general purpose text editor for code development.  I want the default view to directory list view on the left vertical split pane and the file I double click on will be in the right vertical split pane.  This is much the same in netbeans or eclipse.  Is there anyway to set this to be the default mvim view, or hotkeys to put it in this mode?

on my macbook pro, I can open mvim by typing:

```
mvim .
```

This opens a directory tree view of the current directory (not split pane).  If I double click on any files, the whole screen is replaced with that file and my directory listing goes away.  I want to keep it.

If I highlight a file from within the directory listing and click "t" hotkey, a new tab is opened showing the contents of that file (again, not split pane, but whole file in it's own tab).  However, if I highlight a folder and click "t" hotkey, a new tab is opened BUT it  has a new vertical split with directory listing on the left.  Furthermore if I double click on the files in that directory listing, they go in the right pane, which is what I want.

Is there any command line arguments that set that up which I can alias?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be describing [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) plugin almost to the "T". You might need to tweak some variables in your `$VIMRUNTIME` for it work exactly as you describe (e.g., '`let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=0`'), but with a little bit of time with the docs you should be able to get what you want.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I didn't even realize I was using nerdtree.  A friend copied me his .vim dir to give me some colorizations, and then taught me some hotkeys.  All this time I thought it was a feature of mvim.  I looked through the documentation but haven't found exactly what I wanted but thanks.

Comment: @sketchfemme You should check to see. You might not be using NERDTree. My answer was not suggesting that you have NERDTree already installed. It was actually a suggestion that you should *install* NERDTree, and configure it by setting the variable I described. That should give you the behavior you want. The filesystem explorer that ships with Vim (and MacVim) is netrw. That does not give you the behavior you want. NERDTree will, though.

Answer (score 0):

I insert the following code in my ~/.vimrc

```
nmap <silent> <c-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

Then, I use ctrl+n to switch to dual mode.